# UICollectionViewFlowLayout bug, when AlertController presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i wanna present a AlertController in super ViewController. (in fact, theres no CollectionView in it), but when the AlertController presented. there will call some bug in Debug area:

```
//2016-02-25 14:55:06.721 treatα[53173:1063624] the behavior of the 
UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
//2016-02-25 14:55:06.721 treatα[53173:1063624] the item height must 
be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section 
insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and 
bottom values.
//2016-02-25 14:55:06.722 treatα[53173:1063624] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is
 <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc883dfb1d0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc8848de800; 
frame = (0 104.667; 270 44); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc883dfbb50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc883dfb680>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; 
contentSize: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc883dfb1d0>.
//2016-02-25 14:55:06.722 treatα[53173:1063624] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes
             to catch this in the debugger.
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by myself. need to add

```
alert.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

before

```
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

then, bug be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue in my screen for only iphon6 plus screen. Please check, if you are not passing empty title, if title is empty , pass it nil like :

```
 UIAlertController *confirmAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:displayMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

instead of

```
 UIAlertController *confirmAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:displayMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

it fixed my problem. Good luck..